# Different results from poisson glmer and glmmadmb when using emmeans (lsmeans)

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, poisson-regression, lsmeans

Why would I be getting drastically different results from glmer and glmmadmbM for the same model when using emmeans? The results from summary() are the same.

EMmeans
glmer:

```
##  Condition Dimension       rate         SE  df  asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  Cond1     Dim1      0.62962963 0.15270775 Inf 0.39141573 1.0128195
##  Cond2     Dim1      1.00000000 0.20851452 Inf 0.66452621 1.5048315
##  Cond1     Dim2      0.44444444 0.12830046 Inf 0.25240386 0.7825984
##  Cond2     Dim2      0.52173913 0.15061335 Inf 0.29630044 0.9187017
##  Cond1     Dim3      0.11111111 0.06415030 Inf 0.03583554 0.3445094
##  Cond2     Dim3      0.08695652 0.06148800 Inf 0.02174740 0.3476938
##  Cond1     Dim4      0.62962963 0.15270793 Inf 0.39141552 1.0128200
##  Cond2     Dim4      0.34782609 0.12297546 Inf 0.17394664 0.6955178
##  Cond1     Dim5      0.22222222 0.09072157 Inf 0.09983595 0.4946386
##  Cond2     Dim5      0.52173913 0.15061320 Inf 0.29630061 0.9187012
##  Cond1     Dim6      0.55555556 0.14344385 Inf 0.33492546 0.9215244
##  Cond2     Dim6      0.60869565 0.16268074 Inf 0.36050146 1.0277639
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95 
## Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

glmmadmb:

```
##  Condition Dimension      rate         SE  df   asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  Cond1     Dim1      0.3663249 0.05349442 Inf 0.275147407 0.4877164
##  Cond2     Dim1      0.4136632 0.10788837 Inf 0.248109407 0.6896847
##  Cond1     Dim2      0.6296298 0.17603138 Inf 0.364004784 1.0890893
##  Cond2     Dim2      0.9999996 0.45302846 Inf 0.411510701 2.4300684
##  Cond1     Dim3      0.4444386 0.14348993 Inf 0.236045490 0.8368118
##  Cond2     Dim3      0.5217467 0.28670585 Inf 0.177711150 1.5318097
##  Cond1     Dim4      0.1111087 0.06538836 Inf 0.035059774 0.3521170
##  Cond2     Dim4      0.0869379 0.09964245 Inf 0.009196412 0.8218638
##  Cond1     Dim5      0.6296300 0.16326922 Inf 0.378756834 1.0466712
##  Cond2     Dim5      0.3478197 0.19225164 Inf 0.117724364 1.0276421
##  Cond1     Dim6      0.2222084 0.08653129 Inf 0.103583342 0.4766846
##  Cond2     Dim6      0.5217479 0.25848473 Inf 0.197586717 1.3777284
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95 
## Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

Summary coefs--

glmer:

```
## Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
##   Approximation) [glmerMod]
##  Family: poisson  ( log )
## Formula: Value ~ Condition * Dimension + (1 | ID)
##    Data: dat
## 
##      AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
##    532.2    580.3   -253.1    506.2      287 
## 
## Scaled residuals: 
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -1.0000 -0.7223 -0.3333  0.5016  6.4874 
## 
## Random effects:
##  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  ID     (Intercept) 0        0       
## Number of obs: 300, groups:  ID, 50
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)                -1.0042     0.1460  -6.877 6.12e-12 ***
## ConditionCond2              0.1215     0.2157   0.564   0.5730    
## Dimension1                  0.5416     0.2460   2.201   0.0277 *  
## Dimension2                  0.1933     0.2773   0.697   0.4858    
## Dimension3                 -1.1930     0.4935  -2.417   0.0156 *  
## Dimension4                  0.5416     0.2460   2.201   0.0277 *  
## Dimension5                 -0.4999     0.3639  -1.374   0.1696    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension1   0.3411     0.3387   1.007   0.3139    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension2   0.0388     0.3970   0.098   0.9221    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension3  -0.3667     0.7759  -0.473   0.6365    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension4  -0.7150     0.4112  -1.739   0.0821 .  
## ConditionCond2:Dimension5   0.7319     0.4617   1.585   0.1129
```

glmmadmb:

```
## glmmadmb(formula = Value ~ Condition * Dimension + (1 | ID), 
##     data = dat, family = "poisson")
## 
## AIC: 532.2 
## 
## Coefficients:
##                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)                -1.0042     0.1460   -6.88  6.1e-12 ***
## ConditionCond2              0.1215     0.2157    0.56    0.573    
## Dimension1                  0.5416     0.2460    2.20    0.028 *  
## Dimension2                  0.1933     0.2773    0.70    0.486    
## Dimension3                 -1.1930     0.4935   -2.42    0.016 *  
## Dimension4                  0.5416     0.2460    2.20    0.028 *  
## Dimension5                 -0.4999     0.3639   -1.37    0.170    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension1   0.3411     0.3387    1.01    0.314    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension2   0.0388     0.3970    0.10    0.922    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension3  -0.3668     0.7760   -0.47    0.636    
## ConditionCond2:Dimension4  -0.7150     0.4112   -1.74    0.082 .  
## ConditionCond2:Dimension5   0.7320     0.4617    1.59    0.113
```

Reproducible example:

```
dat = structure(list(ID = structure(c(6L, 46L, 37L, 16L, 10L, 7L, 47L, 
12L, 40L, 2L, 28L, 39L, 32L, 43L, 8L, 31L, 25L, 22L, 34L, 5L, 
36L, 17L, 48L, 30L, 33L, 1L, 24L, 26L, 35L, 29L, 38L, 44L, 13L, 
20L, 45L, 15L, 42L, 19L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 49L, 4L, 41L, 18L, 21L, 
23L, 3L, 50L, 27L, 6L, 46L, 37L, 16L, 10L, 7L, 47L, 12L, 40L, 
2L, 28L, 39L, 32L, 43L, 8L, 31L, 25L, 22L, 34L, 5L, 36L, 17L, 
48L, 30L, 33L, 1L, 24L, 26L, 35L, 29L, 38L, 44L, 13L, 20L, 45L, 
15L, 42L, 19L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 49L, 4L, 41L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 
50L, 27L, 6L, 46L, 37L, 16L, 10L, 7L, 47L, 12L, 40L, 2L, 28L, 
39L, 32L, 43L, 8L, 31L, 25L, 22L, 34L, 5L, 36L, 17L, 48L, 30L, 
33L, 1L, 24L, 26L, 35L, 29L, 38L, 44L, 13L, 20L, 45L, 15L, 42L, 
19L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 49L, 4L, 41L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 50L, 27L, 
6L, 46L, 37L, 16L, 10L, 7L, 47L, 12L, 40L, 2L, 28L, 39L, 32L, 
43L, 8L, 31L, 25L, 22L, 34L, 5L, 36L, 17L, 48L, 30L, 33L, 1L, 
24L, 26L, 35L, 29L, 38L, 44L, 13L, 20L, 45L, 15L, 42L, 19L, 11L, 
14L, 9L, 49L, 4L, 41L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 50L, 27L, 6L, 46L, 
37L, 16L, 10L, 7L, 47L, 12L, 40L, 2L, 28L, 39L, 32L, 43L, 8L, 
31L, 25L, 22L, 34L, 5L, 36L, 17L, 48L, 30L, 33L, 1L, 24L, 26L, 
35L, 29L, 38L, 44L, 13L, 20L, 45L, 15L, 42L, 19L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 
49L, 4L, 41L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 50L, 27L, 6L, 46L, 37L, 16L, 
10L, 7L, 47L, 12L, 40L, 2L, 28L, 39L, 32L, 43L, 8L, 31L, 25L, 
22L, 34L, 5L, 36L, 17L, 48L, 30L, 33L, 1L, 24L, 26L, 35L, 29L, 
38L, 44L, 13L, 20L, 45L, 15L, 42L, 19L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 49L, 4L, 
41L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 50L, 27L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
"93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", 
"103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
"112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
"121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
"130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
"139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
"148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
"157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
"166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
"175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", 
"184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", 
"193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", 
"202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", 
"211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
"220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", 
"229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", 
"238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", "246", 
"247", "248", "249", "250"), class = "factor"), Condition = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Cond1", 
"Cond2"), class = "factor"), Dimension = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Dim1", 
"Dim2", "Dim3", "Dim4", "Dim5", "Dim6"), class = "factor", contrasts = structure(c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1), .Dim = 6:5, .Dimnames = list(c("Dim1", 
"Dim2", "Dim3", "Dim4", "Dim5", "Dim6"), NULL))), 
    Value = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-300L))

contrasts(dat$Dimension) <- contr.sum 
dat$ID = as.factor(dat$ID)
tail(contrasts(dat$ID))

glmerM = glmer(Value ~ Condition*Dimension + (1|ID), family=poisson, dat)
summary(glmerM)
emmeans(glmerM, ~Condition*Dimension, type="response")

glmmadmbM = glmmadmb(Value ~ Condition*Dimension + (1|ID),family="poisson", dat)
summary(glmmadmbM)
emmeans(glmmadmbM, ~Condition*Dimension, type="response")
```

Comment: How do the results differ? Do the annotations on the results confirm that in both cases, the results are back-transformed?

Comment: @rvl the estimated marginal means (in the first two outputs I pasted) are different. For example, dimension 1 condition 1 is .63 for the glmer model and .37 for glmmadmb. Looking at the output a little longer I realized some (but not all) of the values moved around to different rows between the two models for some reason (e.g., cond1-dim1 rate in glmer becomes cond1-dim2 in glmmadmb). And they are both back-transformed (indicated in output), but I get the same issue with the log scale emmeans.

Comment: @rvl I seem to have identified the issue, which I think may be a bug in emmeans when using glmmadmb with contrast coding (in my code: `contrasts(dat$Dimension) <- contr.sum `). If I run the code with the automatic dummy coding then both results agree. I checked and the emmeans for the glmer model are the correct ones when using contrast coding. Not sure why emmeans is interpreting glmmadmb's coding incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, well that helps. It’s sometimes hard to figure out where the contrasts actually used are saved (if indeed they were) in the model object. I’ll look at it.

Comment: OK, Now that I'm home from vacation, I looked at the code, and see that the support code looks for `object$contrasts`, which doesn't exist (so is set to `NULL` and the current `getOption("contrasts")` is used). I have a vague memory that I put that in as a placeholder and hoped I could find a way to find the contrasts somewhere. In a `glmerMod` object they are in `attr(object@pp$X, "contrasts")`, but there is no such animal in glmmadmb objects. I'll poke around and see if I can find it somewhere.

Comment: I could not find anywhere where `contrasts` was saved in the object. But you can get the right results if you first `glmmadmbM$contrasts <- list(Condition = "contr.treatment", Dimension = "contr.sum")` before calling `emmeans()`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I went ahead and ran the model without changing the contrasts since I use the em means (not the coefficients) for categorical variables anyway.  If you want to answer the question with this suggestion though I'll accept it. And thanks for following questions and concerns on here and the great work on the package! It's one of the most useful I constantly use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contrasts` attribute is not correctly retrieved in **emmeans**'s current support for `glmmamdb` objects. To make it work in this example, do:

```
glmmamdbM$contrasts <- list(
    Condition = "contr.treatment", Dimension = "contr.sum")
```

... before calling `emmeans()` or `ref_grid()`.

I have figured out how to retrieve this contrast info, at least when it is assigned to individual variables using `contrasts<-`, as in this example. That support will be included with the next update of **emmeans** (version > 1.2.2).